# How to resolve "403 forbidden" errors when running yum update on a local mrepo server

Tags: yum

I'm getting "403 forbidden" errors when trying to run yum update using my local mrepo server.  This is on an air-gapped network and yum.conf has no proxy information, so I don't believe there's a configuration setting blocking updates.  When I browse to individual RPM URLs using a Web browser, I get 403 responses as well.
I verified that all RRMs are open to the world (777).
Thanks,
-Andrew Moon

Comment: Do you have SELinux running on the Server?

Comment: No, it's disabled.